# xcode 3.2: how can i add an include dir to my project?

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, xcode3.2

I can't seem to find in Xcode how can I add an include dir to my project.

how can I do so ?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select your project in the "Groups & Files" panel on the left hand side
2. Open the "Get Info" window (Cmd + I)
3. Select the "Build" tab
4. Find "Header Search Paths"
5. Add the include dirs.

Comment: Alternatively just drag the directory in quesiton, e.g. `/usr/local/include`, to the project window. Not only does this add the appropriate include path, it also means That way you can quickly and easily open up any of the includes that you're using from within Xcode.